# In Multibit HD, is there a way to see all of my receiving addresses?

Tags: wallet, address, multibit

I understand that if I request a payment and delete the request, I still own the address and will receive Bitcoins that were sent to it.  However, I find it very uncomfortable to just "assume" that I own an address.  I would much prefer if I could look somewhere and see a list of the addresses that are mine.

Is there a place I can see all of my addresses?  What are the conditions under which I will no longer own an address?

Answer (score 1):

I guess this question, unanswered for nearly 3 years, is obsolete

According to https://multibit.org/blog/2017/07/26/multibit-shutdown.html (retrieved 2018-08-17)

> Multibit is No Longer Supported
>
> July 26th 2017
>
> Dear Bitcoin Community,
>
> It is time for us to let Multibit go.
>
> KeepKey acquired Multibit a little over 1 year ago. At the time, the engineers who originally built and supported Multibit had announced that they would no longer be working on it or providing support. Multibit played an important role in the Bitcoin infrastructure. We felt that it was important for Multibit to continue and hoped that with our existing support and development teams, we would be able to keep Multibit alive.
>
> The reality is that Multibit is in need of a lot of work. It has stubborn bugs that have caused us and Multibit users much grief. Additionally, Bitcoin has gone through a fundamental change in regards to the way fees work. The addition of SegWit in the coming weeks will mean the Multibit software has fallen still further behind.
>
> Unfortunately, KeepKey simply does not have the resources to support the current issues, nor to rebuild Multibit to ensure ideal user experience. By focusing our attention on the KeepKey device, we will continue building and improving the best hardware wallet available.
>
> Thus, KeepKey will discontinue support and maintenance of Multibit, effective immediately.
>
> We recommend that all Multibit users discontinue using it and you move your keys to other wallet software of your choosing.